# Why cant I dispatch a command from a method outside of the command class and the main plugin class

Tags: java, minecraft

I am using 1.16.2 Spigot library/Bukkit API
My simple code:

```
if (event.getSlot() == 11 && event.getCurrentItem().getType() == Material.STICK) {
        punish.time = " 12 h";
        punish.reason = " Autocane (First Offense)";
        reason = " Autocane (First Offense)";
        punishban();
```

and the punishban method:

```
 public void punishban() {
    reason = " Autocane (First Offense)";

    Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "tempban " + maincommand.target2 + " 12 h" + reason);

}
```

The error message:

```
[20:11:48] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not pass event InventoryClickEvent to punishcommand v1.0.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException: null
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:319) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:70) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:589) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:576) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:2186) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PacketPlayInWindowClick.a(SourceFile:32) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PacketPlayInWindowClick.a(SourceFile:10) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$0(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:19) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeTask(SourceFile:144) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.executeTask(SourceFile:23) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeNext(SourceFile:118) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.ba(MinecraftServer.java:941) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.executeNext(MinecraftServer.java:934) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IAsyncTaskHandler.awaitTasks(SourceFile:127) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.sleepForTick(MinecraftServer.java:918) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:850) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'tempban' in plugin punishcommand v1.0.0
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:756) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.java:693) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at hh_captain.me.guis.banguis.autocanegui.punishban(autocanegui.java:113) ~[?:?]
        at hh_captain.me.guis.banguis.autocanegui.onClick(autocanegui.java:47) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:315) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.command.ColouredConsoleSender cannot be cast to class org.bukkit.entity.Player (org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.command.ColouredConsoleSender and org.bukkit.entity.Player are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at hh_captain.me.bancommand.captain.tempban.tempban.onCommand(tempban.java:29) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:756) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.java:693) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        at hh_captain.me.guis.banguis.autocanegui.punishban(autocanegui.java:113) ~[?:?]
        at hh_captain.me.guis.banguis.autocanegui.onClick(autocanegui.java:47) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:315) ~[spigot-1.16.2.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-0d8350a]
        ... 18 more
```

I'm really struggling to find out why it doesn't work? It works in other occasions like in a commandExecutor method but I have checked through where it says the error is but its literally just the dispatchcommand part so im confused.

Answer (score -1):

nvm i fixed it, I just had to remove the cast in the tempban command because it was being run through console but casted through a player